# How to select unique rows followed by row with highest value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, unique

I have a MySQL database table containing information about places.
I'm trying to fetch all unique categories followed by place with highest rating, but results returned by server does not seems to be accurate.

In database in one category can be few records scored 100 but MySQL would select one that have score 95 for example.

Here is a query:

```
SELECT category, score, title
FROM places 
WHERE active = '1'
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY score DESC
```

is it possible to do that in single query?

**UPDATE**

I have rewrote my query as was suggested to use MySQL function MAX() however returned results are still wrong

here is example of new query

```
SELECT category, MAX(score) AS maxScore, title, score AS realScore
FROM places 
WHERE active = '1'
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: You are only grouping by `category`, so `score` and `title` are arbitrary records in MySQL. Other RDBMS flavors would not run such a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT category
     , MAX(score) AS maxScore
FROM places
WHERE active = '1'
GROUP BY category
```

If you want other fields too, besides the `category` and (maximum) `score`, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.category
     , p.score
     , p.title
     , p.otherfield
     , ...
FROM
    places AS p
  JOIN
    ( SELECT category
           , MAX(score) AS maxScore
      FROM places
      WHERE active = '1'
      GROUP BY category
    ) AS grp
    ON  grp.category = p.category
    AND grp.maxscore = p.score
WHERE p.active = '1'
ORDER BY maxScore DESC
```

As @zekms pointed, this will this will produce multiple rows (with same category) if there are several rows with the same category and max score.

Comment: This can produce unexpected results if there are several rows with the same category and score

Comment: Unexpected no, but multiple, yes. I should add that to the answer, thnx.

Comment: thanks, solution with sub query produce more sophisticated results, more important all values are correct!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT category, MAX(score) max_score
FROM places
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY max_score DESC, RAND()
```

Comment: seems to work, by the way is it possible to shuffle results that share same score, for example if there is 5 places with score 100 can I randomize it?

Comment: unfortunately after validating data I found that returned results are still wrong, category is correct, score  is correct, title is wrong...
Looks like it takes first title from database not the actual one

Comment: @Nazariy: it is not possible, by definition

Comment: Nazariy: yep, this sort of query doesn't imply to have another columns. So you'd better followed @ypercube advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT category, max(score)...
```